# Disable unstable_batchedUpdates() on event handlers in React

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to disable `unstable_batchedUpdates()` in React. I am starting to think it isn't possible. This is what I am trying:

```js
ReactDOM.unstable_batchedUpdates = callback => callback()
```

I am searching for a solution which will help me avoid wrapping the code in event handlers with a `setTimeout()`:

```js
<div onClick={() => {
  setTimeout(() => {
     setInputVisible(true)

     inputRef.current.focus()
  })
}}>
```

Comment: I thought that `ReactDOM.unstable_batchedUpdates` is only an experimental API exposed for users to run batched updates outside of React event handlers. Do these event handlers internally really rely on `ReactDOM.unstable_batchedUpdates` as well? I would have thought they rather rely on a "stable" internal solution.

Answer (score 4):

I finally made progress with a conversation I had with Dan Abramov on GitHub. Posting the conversation here for reference: [Batching makes it difficult to perform imperative actions like focus](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/18402).